# What does %%a mean? (Batch)

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

What does the %%a mean?
I understand the context but not how to use it.
For example  :

```
FOR %%a in (%HELP%) DO echo I don't Know what it means
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`%%a` refers to the name of the variable your for loop will write to.

Quoted from `for /?`:

```
FOR %variable IN (set) DO command [command-parameters]

  %variable  Specifies a single letter replaceable parameter.
  (set)      Specifies a set of one or more files.  Wildcards may be used.
  command    Specifies the command to carry out for each file.
  command-parameters
             Specifies parameters or switches for the specified command.

To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify %%variable instead
of %variable.  Variable names are case sensitive, so %i is different
from %I.
```

#### Example 1:

```
for %%a in (A B C D E) do Echo %%a
```

Produces

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

#### Example 2:

```
for %%a in (A B C) do (for %%b in (1 2 3) do Echo %%a:%%b)
```

Produces

```
A:1
A:2
A:3
B:1
B:2
B:3
C:1
C:2
C:3
```

Comment: How would you set the variable you want the for statement to look for?

Comment: That seems to be very different to what you're currently asking. Why don't you ask that as a new question. Also, if you found my answer helpful please mark it as correct

Comment: You're Welcome Monacraft

Comment: @Moonicorn Thanks, now post your other question and I will look into it

Comment: You can only post once every 90 Mins... XD