# Batch: Searching for keywords in file names using a loop

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, directory, keyword

I am currently working on a small script which is supposed to search for specific keywords in a directory. My current code looks like the following:

```
dir /b /s *<keyword_1>* > results.txt
dir /b /s *<keyword_2>* >> results.txt
dir /b /s *<keyword_3>* >> results.txt
dir /b /s *<keyword_n>* >> results.txt
```

In order to avoid using the same command for n additional keywords, I would like to use a loop instead. As I am quite new to batch scripting, I already figured out that for %%f is probably going to help me in this case. Probably going to look like this:

```
for %%f in (*keyword_1* *keyword_2* *keyword_3* *keyword_n*) do (
dir /b /s *<keyword_xy>* >> results.txt
)
```

My question is now how I can connect the command in the loop with the respective keywords? (first keyword1, then keyword2 and so on...)? Maybe there is also an more easy way to get the job done. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
for %%f in (*keyword_1* *keyword_2* *keyword_3* *keyword_n*) do (
dir /b /s %%f >> results.txt
)
```

For more info [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28689901/9556248) or [Link2](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html).

Comment: Your example and Link1 explained exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no need for any [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop) for this task.

```batch-file
@Dir /B /S /A -D -S -L *keyword_1* *keyword_2* *keyword_3* *keyword_n* > results.txt
```

or using doublequotes if necessary:

```batch-file
@Dir /B /S /A -D -S -L "*keyword_1*" "*keyword_2*" "*keyword_3*" "*keyword_n*" > "results.txt"
```

I have used additional filters to only select files, as opposed to files and directories, and to exclude files with the system attribute, and those which are junctions/mount points/symbolic links. To find out more about those options, open up a Command Prompt window, type `dir /?`, press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key, and read the information presented.

---

Given your provided example, *which no doubt is not reflective of your actual task*,  I suppose you could even use:

```batch-file
@Dir /B /S /A -D -S -L "*keyword_*" > "results.txt"
```

BTW, even if you were intent on using a `For` loop, you'd still minimize it as much as possible:

```batch-file
@(For %%I In (1 2 3 n) Do @Dir /B /S /A -D -S -L "*keyword_%%I*") > "results.txt"
```

If you were to provide a more realistic example of your search strings, we could provide a more focused solution.